# XAML Changing Binding and DataContext Element

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

If I have a class

```
class ContentList 
{
    public string Content1 { get; set; }
    public string Content2 { get; set; }
}
```

and a textbox in my XAML file with a binding

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Content1, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

I set the DataContext in my .cs file by

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    this.DataContext = new ContentList();
}
```

How do I change the binding to Content2?

Also, how do I access and change Content1 in code? this.DataContext.Content1 = "string" does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the binding of your `TextBox` from `Content1` to `Content2`, first give the `TextBox` a name, and then in the code-behind you can do this:

```
myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Content2"));
```

To access `Content1` in the code, you can do this:

```
string content = ((ContentList)this.DataContext).Content1;
```

Comment: The first code give the errors

`'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

so I did this

`Binding d = new Binding();`

`d.Path = new PropertyPath("Content2");`

`myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, d);`

Comment: The right `Binding` class is in `System.Windows.Data`, not `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding`. Is this a Windows Phone app?

Comment: No, this is a Windows 8 app.

Comment: Interesting, I can't see that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You change the Binding to `Content2` by writing `Content2` in the XAML file. You cannot do this dynamically. Well, that's not quite right. It's possible to use the Binding class to establish a new binding in code. But you shouldn't do that in this case because it defeats declarative programming in XAML.

`Content1` may be accessed like this: `((ContentList)DataContext).Content1`

However, this is not the best practice. Try to learn about MVVM.

Comment: you can set the bindings through code by using BindingOperations class.

Comment: I was about to edit my post when you commented. It's too unusual for case like that so I had not thought about it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not being best practice? I try to look it up but I am still not sure. Should the model be static or that changes are done from view? Or that I should create a new DataContext for changes?

Comment: Simply spoken - you give up too many advantages of WPF if you generally do such things from code. This is not a plea against code-behind, but for thoughtful dealing with it. Unfortunately, more details would be beyond the scope of this comment.